# getting two A6 complete booklet sequences from an A4 page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdftk, imposition

I have an a6 pdf book. I'd like to convert it to an a4 pdf so that when I print it, I can cut the a4 page in two (upside and downside will have the same content, so I'll end up with two copies of the book) and when putting together the pages, they can be read in sequence (I think this is called impose)

Supose A,B,C,D are 4 pages of the book. I want the resulting file to be:

```
DA
DA
```

and

```
CD
CD
```

Was I clear?

Sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology.

Answer (score 2):

as suggested, the mighty **Multivalent tools** are the solution, but  they need to be combined with my Script I attach to perform the task you desire

## USAGE:

`2copiesinA4 filename.pdf multivalent relative path`

it needs 2 arguments to be specified:

- 1 argument is the filename with the **pdf** extension,
- 2 argument is the **multivalent relative path**

> for instance, if you have **Multivalent.jar** in **/mnt/home/**, this
> will be the **relative path** you need to pass to  script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
multivalentpath=$2
pages="`pdftk $file dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d : -f2`"
echo $pages
halfpages="`echo -n $(( $pages / 2 ))`"
echo $halfpages
h="$(pdfinfo $file | grep "Page size" | cut -d x -f1 | tr 'Page size:' ' ' | xargs)"
w="$(pdfinfo $file | grep "Page size" | cut -d x -f2  | tr 'pts' ' ' | xargs)"
echo $h
echo $w
doubleheight="`let MULTIPLICATION=$h*2; echo $MULTIPLICATION`"
doublewidth="`let MULTIPLICATION=$w*2; echo $MULTIPLICATION`" 
echo $doubleheight
echo $doublewidth
sequence="`for ((x=$pages, y=1;x>=$halfpages, y<=$halfpages;x--, y++)); do echo "$x $y "; done | awk 'NR %2==1 {print $1, $2, $1, $2 } NR % 2==0 { print $2, $1, $2, $1 }' | xargs | tr " " ","`"
echo $sequence
java -cp "$multivalentpath"Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -verbose -dim 2x2 -paper "$doubleheight"x"$doublewidth"pt -page "$sequence" $file
exit 0
```

## STEPS

#### 1. download latest **free** version of **Multivalent** with tools inside

**Multivalent**

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355/Multivalent20060102.jar.html
  (latest free version with tools included, current has no tools in itself)

put it somewhere on disk, take in mind its **relative path**

---

#### 2. copy the script above in one file and allow to execute (you can name this file *2copiesina4.sh*) and start script

> #### IMPORTANT: CHECK CAREFULLY THAT YOUR PDF HAS A NUMBER OF PAGES *INTEGER MULTIPLE OF 4** (like 4,8, 12, 16...a nd so on)

I uploaded some sample files

- http://ge.tt/92slb5Q/v/2 a pdf in A6 format, 16 pages long
- http://ge.tt/92slb5Q/v/3 the resulting pdf output imposed with help of script above

the resulting **IMPOSED** file looks like this *(see gif animation*

[image: animation of imposing 2 A6 copies in one A4 sheet]

#### STEP 3

once printing finished, you will have the last page that becomes the FIRST of mass of sheet papers you printed

you will cut this papers once in center of paper (at 14.8 cm) on ** A4 long edge** to separate the two block forming the 2 copies of book

[image: first horizontal cut]

and then cut again the two sheet papers blocks to be able to close every resulting sublock on another to have the book with the sequential pages order

[image: second cut]

#NOTE

this is a REDUPLICATION of work normally done to get a so-called **booklet** (an A5 portrait book, printed 2 pages for sheet on an A4 landscape paper) **Obviously, as in our case, the same can be done for an A6 book intended to be printed on A4 to get 2 copies of whole same book, modifying some thing but with the same logic**

imposition sequence, needs that sequence of pages will be this:

**last - first, second - penultimate, ante-penultimate -third ... and so on...**

for a 16 pages book, the imposition sequence will be:

**16 1, 2 15, 14 3, 4 13, 12 5, 6 11, 10 7, 8 9**

in our case, since we want get **TWO** COMPLETE COPIES of same book on an A4 paper, we repeated this sequence **two times** in same sheet

I also developed a way to get **ONE SINGLE** A6 booklet copy, for my personal needs, on an A4 paper, if you need **ONLY ONE** A6 copy of your book printed using A4 sheet papers

Answer (score 0):

You want to "impose" your PDF pages ,  multivalent can do that  http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/pdf/Impose.html