# Printing two A6 booklet sequences from one A4 page

Tags: pdf, printing

This question is in regards to this answer that was made a long time ago:

[getting two A6 complete booklet sequences from an A4 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028724/getting-two-a6-complete-booklet-sequences-from-an-a4-page)

I have been trying to create this imposed pdf for a long time using the script but nothing is happening.

First of all I am a n00b in anything related to scripting but can do it when its necessary.

Here is what I did:

```
I copied the script in text file and changed the extension to .ch and named it new.ch and changed the following values:
```

file=$1 multivalentpath=$2

to

file=$abc.pdf multivalentpath=$D:\Multivalent.

```
I put the multivalent.jar file, pdf file and the script in a single folder.

I wrote:
```

new abc.pdf multivalent relative path

but nothing happens. Can you please help me out here.

Masud

Comment: It seems you tried to use a bash script for Linux, on a Microsoft OS

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting two A6 complete booklet sequences from an A4 page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028724/getting-two-a6-complete-booklet-sequences-from-an-a4-page)

Comment: Hi Dingo! Thanks for replying. I am using win 7. any suggestions what I should be doing?